# Higher moments arbitrage

Tags: volatility, arbitrage, skewness, kurtosis

Is there concrete evidence that statistical arbitrage (historical vs. implied) on higher moments, specifically skewness and kurtosis, can be (significantly) done?

Working from [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471733873) source, the author finds clear evidence on volatility arbitrage. Which is mainstream, very well understood, and heavily done (e.g. VIX trading). But, to take the discussion further, [this](http://imcs.dvfu.ru/lib.int/docs/Non-tech/Management/Applied%20Quantitative%20Finance.pdf) research (Chapter 9 - Trading on Deviations of Implied and Historical Distributions) is specifically addressing this question, applied on DAX data, which is not a as liquid as the equivalent US options markets.

Therefore, my main question is: has anyone done any empirical work on this topic and could relate to it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this would qualify as "empirical work" but you should definitely read [Dynamic Hedging](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UG9JQA) if you haven't already. Taleb talks a lot about this. To be more specific, have a look at page 264, the section called "Higher Moment Bets". I hope this is helpful, although I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.